# how to unit test that an Angular controller has changed the route

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to figure out how to test my controller logic that deals with changing the route, but even though the code works in the browser, when the test runs the code it doesn't seem to change the route.

Here is a simplified version of my controller

```
myApp.controller('locationController', ['$location',
    function($location) {
        'use strict';
        $location.path('/dashboard');
    }
]);
```

And the simplest level of test, just checking that the controller is loaded and that the route changes from what it is initially set to over to something else

```
describe('Testing c-app-controller logic', function() {
    var ctrl,
        $scope,
        $rootScope,
        location,
        route;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('optApp');
        inject(function (_$rootScope_, $controller, _api_, _$location_, $httpBackend, $route) {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            location = _$location_;
            route = $route;
            ctrl = $controller('locationController', {
                $scope: $scope,
                $rootScope: _$rootScope_,
                location: _$location_,
                route: $route
            });
        });
    });

    describe('location controller', function () {
        it('should change location', function () {
            location.path('/login');
            expect(route.current.controller).toBe('locationController');
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect(location.path()).toBe('/dashboard');
        });
    });

});
```

Here's what I get:

```
Expected '/login' to be '/dashboard'.
Error: Expected '/login' to be '/dashboard'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm weird, I seem to have found a way to get it to work. Some strange stuff to how Angular digest is running in test, but if I wrap the code in a function and call the function from the test, I can get the route to change and the test to succeed.

controller

```
myApp.controller('locationController', ['$location',
    function($location) {
        'use strict';
        $scope.changeLocation = function(){
            $location.path('/dashboard');
        }
    }
]);
```

test

```
describe('Testing c-app-controller logic', function() {
    var ctrl,
        $scope,
        $rootScope,
        location,
        route;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('optApp');
        inject(function (_$rootScope_, $controller, _api_, _$location_, $httpBackend, $route) {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            location = _$location_;
            route = $route;
            ctrl = $controller('locationController', {
                $scope: $scope,
                $rootScope: _$rootScope_,
                location: _$location_,
                route: $route
            });
        });
    });

    describe('location controller', function () {
        it('should change location', function () {
            location.path('/login');
            expect(route.current.controller).toBe('locationController');
            $scope.changeLocation();
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect(location.path()).toBe('/dashboard');
        });
    });

});
```